# Unexpected error occurred: Error code 8

Tags: javascript, apache, internet-explorer

I have this issue called **Error 8** occurring in my website.

Occurrence of this issue is random. Few times it occurred when users are typing a note in website and when they click submit, Error 8 issue pops up. Mainly it is occurring where many Ajax request are happening in the same page.

### Request - Response

Request:

```
Client IE Browser -> Javascipt sents Ajax request -> Apache web 
         server -> Application server (Zope)
```

Response: `Zope -> Apache -> Javascript -> IE Browser`

### Sequence of operations which occurs is as follows

1. Open Website in IE 11 (mode changed to IE 8)
2. Without any issue, login in happens
3. One specific request to server which is sent from Javascript gets 
   aborted (as seen in the debugger)
4. No request in Apache access or error log
5. No request in Application server(zope)

### What we have noted till now

1. Issue happens when many simultaneous Ajax call happens
2. In those request, one of the request gets aborted
3. Refreshing that or resending that request goes through fine
4. No reproducible in other browsers. Only happening in IE
5. Suspecting cache issue in IE

What could cause this Error 8 issue to occur in IE. Could IE have issue with caching !! How to resolve it. Any help is appreciated !!

If there are more information needed from my side please let me know which one.
The screenshot of the error:

[image: Error 8 issue]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: @DimaSan Thank you for the post edit.